# How to convert an element into 2 elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this element:

```
<h4>username (role) on 26 Nov 2018 20:39:42 +00:00:</h4>
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
<h4>username (role)</h4>
<p>on 26 Nov 2018 20:39:42 +00:00:</p>
```

There will always be 2 words in the `<h4>` element, but those words will vary. The `<p>` element will be dynamically updated to the current date and time, but will always start with "on" and end with "00:".

How can I achieve this outcome? I'm using jQuery but am fairly new to it, so I can't seem to find the right approach.

Comment: Where does your initial element come from? Fix it there.

Comment: To expand upon Kosh Very's point-- this could probably be achieved with jQuery, but if you are pushing it to the page, or have any control over the html going in, it would be better to fix it up front than manipulating it after the fact.

Comment: This is a pretty old website, and I don't completely understand how it is actually being rendered. I know that it is going through a markdown generator and stored in a database. I was told that changing the actual format of this would break historical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on `on` and then use `after()` to create a new `p`:

```js
$('h4').each(function() {  // use an each so it will work if there are multiple on a page
  var $h4 = $(this),
    text = $h4.text(),
    textParts = text.split(' on');   // split on ` on`

  if (textParts.length == 2) {       // only update if there is a paragraph
    $h4.text(textParts[0]).after('<p>on ' + textParts[1] + '</p>');  // update the h4 text and put the new paragraph after it
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>username (role) on 26 Nov 2018 20:39:42 +00:00:</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to fix this kind of cases without the use of the JS code, but if you don't have access to the source and you really need a JS soltion, check this one:

```js
var h4_p = $('h4').text().split(' on');
$('h4').text(h4_p[0]);
$('<p>on ' + h4_p[1] + '</p>').insertAfter($('h4'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>username (role) on 26 Nov 2018 20:39:42 +00:00:</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```js
// gets the header element and caches it since we use it twice
let header = $('h4');
// get header text
let headerText = header.text();
// run regex to get the items we need
let result = /(.*?) (on .*)/i.exec(headerText);
// create a new header for the first group found
let newHeader = '<h4>' + result[1] + '</h4>';
// create the paragraph with the second group found
let newParagraph = '<p>' + result[2] + '</p>';
// replace the current header with the new one
header.replaceWith(newHeader + newParagraph);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>username (role) on 26 Nov 2018 20:39:42 +00:00:</h4>
```

### Description

This answer utilizes regex and jquery to get the current header and then create the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
var split = $("h4").text().split(" ");
var newhtml = "<h4>"+split[0]+" "+split[1]+"</h4>";
newhtml += "<p>";
for(i = 2; i < split.length;i++){
  newhtml += split[i]+" ";
}

newhtml += "</p>";

alert(newhtml)
```

Comment: this doesn't create any elements just makes an alert

Comment: Yes I thought they could figure out how to edit HTML.